# How to render Mapbox vector tiles only within a specific country's boundaries?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, country, vector-tiles

I'm working on rendering some vector tiles using Mapbox Gl JS. These tiles are within the US and Canada, but I need only those within US boundaries to be rendered.

My tileset has the following metadata: gsd, name, miles. There is no metadata that indicates the country itself.

Is there a way to render only the tiles within a specific boundary? I tried with queryRenderedFeatures, but I need a solution with the tiles within precise US boundaries.

I cannot add the tileset URL here because it's part of proprietary software.

Answer (score 0):

There's no straightforward way of doing that, for the reasons you describe.

You can try something like generating a shape which is the inverse of the US (ie, the whole world with the US cut out of it) and overlaying it, to block out everything else. But it will cut off labels and look...not great.